# encrypt data in NSUserDefaults Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption

I have a simple login (username and password) and I set data in NSUserDefaults for the next login time with touchID the user can access fastly, and the way is, verify the touchID and make a login with data from NSUserDefaults, so I need to encrypt the password... save the password encrypted and when the touchID would be correct decrypt the password and make the login

Comment: use keyChain to save password is ment for that

Comment: but it works with encryptation??

Comment: keychain save data encripted in device, so you don have to handle it back, is the secure way to save stuff encripted in device.